# Selecting only top parent table row with all of it's children table rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have two tables:

```
#ProjectHealthReports
Id | From       | SubmittedOn
1  | 2020-01-01 |
2  | 2020-02-01 | 2020-10-23
3  | 2020-03-01 |
4  | 2020-04-01 | 2020-10-23
5  | 2020-05-01 | 2020-10-23


#ProjectHealthReportItems
Id | Note                                      | ProjectHealthReportId
1  | First for 2020-01-01                      | 1
2  | Second for 2020-01-01                     | 1
3  | First for 2020-02-01                      | 2
4  | Second for 2020-02-01                     | 2
5  | First for 2020-03-01                      | 3
6  | Second for 2020-03-01                     | 3
7  | First for 2020-04-01                      | 4
8  | Second for 2020-04-01                     | 4
9  | (We want this one) First for 2020-05-01   | 5
10 | (We want this one) Second for 2020-05-01  | 5
```

How can I get all `#ProjectHealthReportItems` and `#ProjectHealthReport` details for the last `From` date which has value for `SubmittedOn` (so in this case it would be ProjectHealthReport 5 and ProjectHealthReportItems 9, 10).

Basically, I need something like this just, obviously without `top 1` as it only returns one row and I need, in this case, to return 2 rows :)

```
select top 1 phr.Id, phr.[From], phr.SubmittedOn, phri.Note from #ProjectHealthReports phr
inner join #ProjectHealthReportItems phri on phr.Id = phri.ProjectHealthReportId
where phr.SubmittedOn is not null
order by phr.[From] desc
```

Here is the SQL for creating and seeding the tables

```
create table #ProjectHealthReports(
    Id int primary key,
    [From] date not null ,
    SubmittedOn date null
)
go
create table #ProjectHealthReportItems(
    Id int primary key,
    Note nvarchar(max),
    ProjectHealthReportId int constraint FK_PHR references #ProjectHealthReports
)
go

insert into #ProjectHealthReports(Id, [From], SubmittedOn)
values (1, '2020-01-01', null),
       (2, '2020-02-01', getutcdate()),
       (3, '2020-03-01', null),
       (4, '2020-04-01', getutcdate()),
       (5, '2020-05-01', getutcdate())
go

insert into #ProjectHealthReportItems(Id, Note, ProjectHealthReportId)
values (1, 'First for 2020-01-01', 1),
       (2, 'Second for 2020-01-01', 1),
       (3, 'First for 2020-02-01', 2),
       (4, 'Second for 2020-02-01', 2),
       (5, 'First for 2020-03-01', 3),
       (6, 'Second for 2020-03-01', 3),
       (7, 'First for 2020-04-01', 4),
       (8, 'Second for 2020-04-01', 4),
       (9, '(We want this one) First for 2020-05-01', 5),
       (10, '(We want this one) Second for 2020-05-01', 5)
go
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First select top then join

```
   select t.*, phri.Note
   from (select top(1) phr.Id phrid, phr.[From], phr.SubmittedOn
         from #ProjectHealthReports phr
         where phr.SubmittedOn is not null
         order by phr.[From] desc) t
   inner join #ProjectHealthReportItems phri on t.phrId =   phri.ProjectHealthReportId
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest window functions:

```
select phr.*, phri.*
from #ProjectHealthReports phr left join
     (select phri.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ProjectHealthReportId order by id desc) as seqnum
      from #ProjectHealthReportItems phri
     ) phri
     on phr.Id = phri.ProjectHealthReportId and seqnum = 1
order by phr.[From] desc;
```

You can also do this using filtering in the `where`, such as correlated subquery:

```
select phr.*, phri.*
from #ProjectHealthReports phr join
     #ProjectHealthReportItems phri
     on phr.Id = phri.ProjectHealthReportId and seqnum = 1
where phri.id = (select max(phri2.id)
                 from #ProjectHealthReportItems phri2
                 where phri2.ProjectHealthReportId = phri.ProjectHealthReportId
                )
order by phr.[From] desc
```

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way to do this without a LEFT JOIN would be assign a row number, using the `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function, to the #ProjectHealthReports table.  Something like this

```
with lv_cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by [From] desc) rn
    from #ProjectHealthReports)
select l.*, phri.* 
from lv_cte l
     join #ProjectHealthReportItems phri on l.id=phri.ProjectHealthReportId
where l.rn=1;
```

Output

```
Id  From        SubmittedOn rn  Id  Note                              ProjectHealthReportId
5   2020-05-01  2020-10-23  1   9   (We want this one) First for 2020-05-01 5
5   2020-05-01  2020-10-23  1   10  (We want this one) Second for 2020-05-01    5
```